# apt-get error after installing linux-image-rpi-rpfv and linux-headers-rpi-rpfv

Tags: raspbian

i have a problem on the apt-get command after installing:linux-image-rpi-rpfv and linux-headers-rpi-rpfv

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree        
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up linux-image-4.9.0-6-rpi (4.9.82-1+deb9u3+rpi1) ...
    No diversion 'diversion of /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-rpi by rpikernelhack', none removed.
    No diversion 'diversion of /boot/config-4.9.0-6-rpi by rpikernelhack', none removed.
    No diversion 'diversion of /boot/System.map-4.9.0-6-rpi by rpikernelhack', none removed.
    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-rpi

    gzip: stdout: No space left on device
    E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
    update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-rpi with 1.
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.9.0-6-rpi (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-rpi-rpfv:
     linux-image-rpi-rpfv depends on linux-image-4.9.0-6-rpi; however:
      Package linux-image-4.9.0-6-rpi is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-rpi-rpfv (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-4.9.0-6-rpi
     linux-image-rpi-rpfv
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ran out of space on your SD card. You can type

```
df -h
```

in a terminal to verify.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer from *@T.M.*: you are using `sudo apt-get -f install` that means fix a broken installation. You have done an installation before that also terminated with an error. The important message here is:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

That means what it says: your storage is full. There is no space left to update the *initramfs* by gzip. Look with: `df -h` what device has no space *Avail* and clean it up to get some more space.

Btw.: A default Raspbian installation do not use an init ramdisk. Maybe your special installation eats the storage space?

Comment: @PedroGuijas Your comment is unreadable. Please edit your question and insert the output.